# Android application force closed when its opening

Tags: java, android, compiler-errors, forceclose

I'am trying to creat an image that opens a new activity when it is clicked.. i tried, i tried..but finally i think i succed.. I have no errors, i checked the manifest, i declared all the activities but the app is stil force closing when it starts and I cant figure it why..

Here are my codes:

Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.QEwqewqewq"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.QEwqewqewq.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
        android:name="Doi"
        android:label="Doi">
</activity>

    </application>


</manifest>
```

main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:gravity="center"
   >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image_id"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/water"
    android:onClick="onClick"  
 android:contentDescription="@null" />

</LinearLayout>
```

And the MainActivity.java:

```
package com.QEwqewqewq;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;

class MainActivity extends Activity{
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }

        public void onClick(View view) {

            if( view.getId() == R.id.image_id)
                startActivity(new Intent(this, Doi.class));
            else
                Log.i("Image", "Try to open the Activity from another view different from ImageView");
        } 
    }
```

Thanks and please help me soon.

EDIT:

LOGCAT:

```
01-27 16:21:41.504: E/AndroidRuntime(288): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-27 16:21:41.504: E/AndroidRuntime(288): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.QEwqewqewq/com.QEwqewqewq.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalAccessException: access to class not allowed
01-27 16:21:41.504: E/AndroidRuntime(288):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2585)
01-27 16:21:41.504: E/AndroidRuntime(288):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
01-27 16:21:41.504: E/AndroidRuntime(288):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
01-27 16:21:41.504: E/AndroidRuntime(288):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
01-27 16:21:41.504: E/AndroidRuntime(288):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-27 16:21:41.504: E/AndroidRuntime(288):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
01-27 16:21:41.504: E/AndroidRuntime(288):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
01-27 16:21:41.504: E/AndroidRuntime(288):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-27 16:21:41.504: E/AndroidRuntime(288):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
01-27 16:21:41.504: E/AndroidRuntime(288):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
01-27 16:21:41.504: E/AndroidRuntime(288):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
01-27 16:21:41.504: E/AndroidRuntime(288):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-27 16:21:41.504: E/AndroidRuntime(288): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessException: access to class not allowed
01-27 16:21:41.504: E/AndroidRuntime(288):  at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
01-27 16:21:41.504: E/AndroidRuntime(288):  at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1429)
01-27 16:21:41.504: E/AndroidRuntime(288):  at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1021)
01-27 16:21:41.504: E/AndroidRuntime(288):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2577)
01-27 16:21:41.504: E/AndroidRuntime(288):  ... 11 more
```

Doi.java:

```
package com.QEwqewqewq;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class Doi extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.setContentView(R.layout.doi);

    }
}
```

Comment: We help you as soon as you show us your LogCat ;)

Comment: Logcat please, there are always errors.

Comment: I'am editing my first post.

Comment: Please post `Doi.java`

Answer (score 0):

try inserting a 'public' in your `MainActivity` class:

```
[...]
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;

public class MainActivity extends Activity{
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
[...]
```

Comment: That was.. you're awsome guys. Thank you very much.. very greatful !

Comment: You're welcome! As Emmanuel said, please mark my answer as solution with the green check on the left.

Answer (score 0):

Make your "MainActivity" public Activity.

Comment: That was.. you're awsome guys. Thank you very much.. very greatful !